# Probability Distribution of X-Y

Tags: probability-distributions, improper-integrals

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous RV jointly distributed with PDF
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
6e^{-(2x+3y)} \text{ for } x,y\geq 0.
$$
The PDF takes value $0$ for other values of $x,y$. Clearly, $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I would want to find the probability of $P(X>Y)$.

The usual (easy) way is to take double integrals and to compute
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}6e^{-(2x+3y)}dxdy=\frac{3}{5}.
$$

However, I was thinking another way by letting $Z=X-Y$ and using the convolution integral
$$
P(X>Y)=P(Z>0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_Y(x-z)dxdz=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}6e^{-(2x+3(x-z))}dxdz.
$$
But, the integral above does not converge. I am not clear whether where when wrong in the convolution integral. Would appreciate if anyone can point it out to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f_Y(x-z) = 0$ if $x < z$, thus
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_Y(x-z)dxdz = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{z}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_Y(x-z)dxdz = \frac{3}{5}.
$$